# VBA - populating cell value based on another cell's value (code not working)

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried to write the below code so depending on the value in cell worksheets "2. Survey" cell f11 then i want "yes" or no value to appear in my current tab cell e59 (current tab - 3. Unit Specification). Im currently getting run time error 9 but don't know why. (probably done something dumb)

```
 Worksheets("3.Unit Specification").Range("e59").Formula = "=IF('2. 
 Survey'!F11=""Mains"",""Yes"","")"
```

run time error 9 is my current issue i just want the cell e59 to have the value yes or have no value (this is a drop down box though and the value is an exact match to the list so don't know if that is resulting in the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double up all the quotes. You missed the last pair.

```
Worksheets("3.Unit Specification").Range("e59").Formula = _
                             "=IF('2. Survey'!F11=""Mains"",""Yes"","""")"
```

Edit

```
'Non-formula approaches

If Worksheets("2. Survey").Range("F11").Value = "Mains" Then
    Worksheets("3.Unit Specification").Range("e59").Value = "Yes"
Else
    Worksheets("3.Unit Specification").Range("e59").Value = ""
End If

'OR

Worksheets("3.Unit Specification").Range("e59").Value = IIf(Worksheets("2. Survey").Range("F11").Value = "Mains", "Yes", "")
```

Comment: i realised and tried that still get the error though :/

Comment: Works for me. Check the sheet names are exactly right, particularly spaces.

Comment: Ok issue. 1) I missed a second space in the sheet name - so this now works (feel like a tool)

2) though my box is a drop down box and i only want the value not the formula to be displayed - temp fix do in another cell and copy and paste value - but is the a decent fix? lol

Comment: Most of us have probably spent time searching for errant spaces at some time or another.

Comment: 3. unit instead of 3.unit - like not even a hard one to see hahaha but is their a fix to my current issue? or do i just have to do my temp fix and hide it with formatting?

Comment: You don't want the formula to appear? You can hide the formula bar (which will affect all cells) or hide the cell's row or column ? Or use VBA to not have a formula at all.

Comment: how do i do the latter? i've already hide the formula bar but as the cell is a combo box "yes","no","" are the only options so the formula when pasting doesn't work in the combo box it works in a free text cell but i just want the last part of the formula the answers as such) to paste into the cell.

i've also ticked your answer as what you said is right but my negligence is why it didn't work haha

Comment: oh wait this works! i just put cell 59 instead of e59 jezzzz i'm having a bad day! enjoy your weekend many thanks!

Comment: OK, I've added a couple of suggestions in case useful. This way you're putting the result directly into the cell.

Comment: many thanks! pretty obvious now i've seen them can't believe i didn't figure that out :') must be the vibes of the weekend approaching.